# Error while Creating a Sales Order Details Using Acumatica REST API

Tags: c#, rest, api

I am trying to Create Sales Order from Acumatica RestAPI by using the below API URL:

http://{url}/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder?ScreenID=SO301000

```
{
    "OrderType": {
        "value": "SO"
    },
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "abcd"
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "Open"
    },    
    "Details":    
    {    
        "InventoryID": {
            "value": "XXX-XX-X"
        },    
        "OrderQty": {
            "value": 2.000000
        },    
        "UnitPrice": {
            "value": 3.450000
        }    
    }
}
```

The response I am getting when calling the RestAPI is:

> Response from Postman Status: 400 Bad Request

But when I use Square Brackets after Details []
The response I am getting  REST API is:

> Response from Postman Status: 200 Ok

```
 {
    "OrderType": {
        "value": "SO"
    },
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "C00008121"
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "Open"
    },    
    "Details": [    
        {    
            "InventoryID": {
                "value": "9387-658-L"
            },    
            "OrderQty": {
                "value": 2.000000
            },    
            "UnitPrice": {
                "value": 3.450000
            }    
        }    
    ]
 }
```

While trying to call REST API from C#.NET I get error as 400 Bad Result

Comment: So `Details` is array?

Comment: Yes Details is an array in Acumatica ERP